# Silverlight webapplication white screen of death

Tags: silverlight

I'm having an white screen of death when trying to debug my silverlight application. The problem is that I don't know what causes it and I don't get any type of information from either Visual Studio or the browser itself (IE9). Breakpoints won't be hit as `App()` in the `App.xml.cs` doesn't get fired either.

The application works fine on my own laptop, but I'm trying to make final adjustments to it on the server which will host the application once it's done. The problem occures on this server.

Would there be any way to get information about what's causing it or did someone experience simulair issues?

Comment: I would check the styles you have in your application especially if you have a resourceDictionary pulling in alot. A missing style can give you a white screen.

Answer (score 1):

hit <kbd>F12</kbd> in IE and go to network and start capturing. You should see your error there if something went wrong downloading and also if there was a problem with the Silverlight plugin (check Console or Script tag).

Answer (score 0):

There could be a number of reasons for this including problems with database connectivity, WCF services, and many other factors.  One thing that might help you get some information is a product called [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).  If you are able to download and install that on your development machine, you can have it running when you try and access your application on the server.  It will give you messages for every step of your application initialization, including database authentication, service authentication, the xap file transfer, etc.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was related to init params not loading up from the web project's .aspx page, try having a look at this if you are having "white death screen" issues.